# How do I allow vars to be accessed by any class/method?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Person {
     public String name;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Person().enter();
     }
     void enter(){
        Person a = new Person();
        String first = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your first name");
        a.name = first;
        new la().a();
     }
}
class la{
     void a(){
        Person a = new Person();
        System.out.println(a.name);
    }
}
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do here is to set global var 'name' from the `JOption` input and to then be able to access 'name' with the new inputted var, from other classes later on. Since the workings of the classes later on depend on that var 'name'. Now I know I can simply pass these on through constructors to the relevant classes and avert this problem, but I want to know if *this* way is possible at all ?

Comment: I am confused. Lot of new Person(), any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, declaring a field public is a way to allow access from all contexts to the field.

Comment: Rather than answering your question, I recommend you to (re)study the OOP concepts.

Comment: @davidmontoyago especially MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're example won't achieve what you are trying to achieve.

You create a new instance `Person` in `Main`, assign it a new, then create a new instance of `la`, which creates it's own instance `Person`

There is no coalition between these various instances.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String first = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your first name");
    // You should be checking the return result, but any way...
    Person person = new Person();
    person.name = first;

    La la = new La(person);

}

public class La {
    public La(Person person) {
        System.out.println(person.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now by not specifying that your class is Public you are setting it as Default. Default is package private so classes in other packages will not have access to this class's public vars.

Declare the class as Public and set any global vars to Public and they will be accessible.